# Multiple vpn connections with site or applications based rules

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have two vpn configurations with openvpn. One for work and the other one for personal. And I'm looking for a way to use each VPN simultaneously, with rules based on applications or remote ip addresses.

for example, for remote addresses ending with google.com (e.g. passwords.google.com) , use the personal vpn connection.

for remote addresses ending with my company's domain, use corporate vpn configuration.

Or an application based configuration : 
use firefox with personal vpn 
use chrome with corporate vpn

Is that possible ?